# How can I index by line in a spinbox, rather than by character number?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, indexing, tkinter

I am trying to populate 2 spinboxes with different values from a single text file (file.txt). I manage this by searching for 'banners' (the TITLE's) within the file and populating each one with the values in-between 2 given banners.

'file.txt' would be something like this:

(without the extra newlines)

............ #exactly 12 to match with the patterns in the code

TITLE 1

............

first thing

second thing

............

TITLE 2

............

primary

secondary

............

TITLE 3

............

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import re

root = Tk()

class Main():

    def __init__(self, root):
        pass

    def Thing1():
        read_thing = open('file.txt', 'r')
        read_names = read_thing.read()
        print (read_names)
        pattern3 =r'^(............)$\
    ^(TITLE 1)$\
    ^(............)$'
        pattern4 = r'^(............)$\
    ^(TITLE 2)$\
    ^(............)$'
        multiline3 = re.compile(pattern3, re.MULTILINE)
        multiline4 = re.compile(pattern4, re.MULTILINE)
        for match in multiline3.finditer(read_names):
            s=match.start()
            e=match.end()
        for match in multiline4.finditer(read_names):
            s1=match.start()
            e1=match.end()
            output = (read_names[e: s1])
            print (output)
            return output

    def Thing2():
        read_thing = open('file.txt', 'r')
        read_names = read_thing.read()
        print (read_names)
        pattern4 =r'^(............)$\
    ^(TITLE 2)$\
    ^(............)$'
        pattern5 = r'^(............)$\
    ^(TITLE 3)$\
    ^(............)$'
        multiline4 = re.compile(pattern4, re.MULTILINE)
        multiline5 = re.compile(pattern5, re.MULTILINE)
        for match in multiline4.finditer(read_names):
            s=match.start()
            e=match.end()
        for match in multiline5.finditer(read_names):
            s1=match.start()
            e1=match.end()
            output = (read_names[e: s1])
            print (output)
            return output

    values1 = Main.Thing1()
    values2 = Main.Thing2()

    def sb1_changed():
        selected = var1.get()
        idx = values1.index(selected)
        print('selected:', selected)
        print('index', idx)
        var2.set(values2[idx])

    def sb2_changed():
        selected = var2.get()
        idx = values2.index(selected)
        print('selected:', selected)
        print('index', idx)
        var1.set(values1[idx])

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()

spinbox1=tk.Spinbox(self, textvariable=var1, values=values1,
                                   command=sb1_changed)
spinbox1.pack()
spinbox2=tk.Spinbox(self, textvariable=var2, values=values2,
                                   command=sb2_changed)
spinbox2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The idea with sb1_changed and sb2_changed is that as I scroll through and therefore select different values in 1 spinbox, I should also be simultaneously scrolling through the different values in the other spinbox.

However, what actually happens is that scrolling through one of the spinboxes *does* scroll through the other, but I can only see individual characters, rather than entire words. So it seems that the index is corresponding to character numbers rather than lines. How can I get it to correspond to lines?

Comment: create simple, working example to run it.

Comment: This is a working example, that does run. With a previous comment (now deleted) you seemed to point out my problem. Do you have a solution? An example of my problem might help: If I have 'first' in sb1 and 'primary' in sb2 as the initial values, scrolling through sb1 gives me the first index character of sb2 ie:'p'. How can I make it give me 'primary' instead?

Comment: it is not working example - I can't simple copy-paste to run it. You put only some class and Spinboxes but it is not enough to run it.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I have edited it to make it closer to runnable. But in order to run it, you will need a .txt file which has 20 values (10 for each spinbox) in it which are separated by the patterns as shown in the code. Sorry I cannot do better than that, all the values coming from 1 file is important to what I am producing.

Comment: you can add it question text with two examples for every spinbox so we can save it in `file.txt`

Comment: BTW: It seems you have wrong indentions in code - only `__init__` is class method.

Comment: any def past __init__ to be a class method should be indented an extra 4 spaces?

Comment: I made some example file and I thing I found problem. You return one string but you have to convert it into list - `return output.strip().split()`

Comment: Thanks - this solution definitely brings me closer to what I want. However, if,like in my example of file.txt, i have a two or more word value in sb1, eg:'first thing' this solution splits them as separate entries. I need them to be a single entry.

Comment: then split only on new-line `split('\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because `Thing1()` and `Thing2()` return everthing as one string and `spinbox` expects list - so you have to convert this string to list

```
return output.strip().split()
```

Code (after some modifications) which I was using

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

def thing(patternA, patternB):
    read_thing = open('file.txt', 'r')
    read_names = read_thing.read()

    print(read_names)

    multilineA = re.compile(patternA, re.MULTILINE)
    multilineB = re.compile(patternB, re.MULTILINE)

    for match in multilineA.finditer(read_names):
        s = match.start()
        e = match.end()
        print('[DEBUG] s,e:', s, e)

    for match in multilineB.finditer(read_names):
        s1 = match.start()
        e1 = match.end()
        print('[DEBUG] s1,e1:', s1, e1)
        output = read_names[e: s1]
        print('[DEBUG] output:', output)
        return output.strip().split("\n")

def thing1():
    pattern3 =r'^(............)$\
^(TITLE 1)$\
^(............)$'
    pattern4 = r'^(............)$\
^(TITLE 2)$\
^(............)$'

    return thing(pattern3, pattern4)

def thing2():
    pattern4 =r'^(............)$\
^(TITLE 2)$\
^(............)$'
    pattern5 = r'^(............)$\
^(TITLE 3)$\
^(............)$'

    return thing(pattern4, pattern5)

def sb1_changed():
    selected = var1.get()
    idx = values1.index(selected)
    print('selected:', selected)
    print('index', idx)
    var2.set(values2[idx])

def sb2_changed():
    selected = var2.get()
    idx = values2.index(selected)
    print('selected:', selected)
    print('index', idx)
    var1.set(values1[idx])

# --- main ---

values1 = thing1()
values2 = thing2()

print('[DEBUG] values1:', values1)
print('[DEBUG] values2:', values2)

root = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()

spinbox1 = tk.Spinbox(root, textvariable=var1, values=values1,
                                   command=sb1_changed)
spinbox1.pack()

spinbox2 = tk.Spinbox(root, textvariable=var2, values=values2,
                                   command=sb2_changed)
spinbox2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And `file.txt` for test

```
AA        01
AA        02
AA        03
AA        04
AA        05
TITLE 1
BB        01
BB        02
BB        03
BB        04
BB        05
TITLE 2
CC        01
CC        02
CC        03
CC        04
CC        05
TITLE 3
DD        01
DD        02
DD        03
DD        04
DD        05
TITLE 4
EE        01
EE        02
EE        03
EE        04
EE        05
```

Comment: I changed `thing1` and `thing2` because they do almost the same.

Comment: I changed `.split()` into `.split("\n")` and used new `file.txt` with spaces.